# How do I add products to purchase order in Odoo using xml-rpc?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Im creating the order:

```
new_order = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
            'purchase.order', 'create',
            [{'partner_id':VENDOR_ID_soucastky,'product_uom':1, 'bom_id':product.odoo_id, 'product_qty': 1.0}],)
```

and then I need to add the products  but I can't find how

odoo v9
P.S. I need to use the webservice API as I don't have aces to change the code on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your purchase order. Then create the purchase order lines and give them an order_id of your newly created purchase order.

```
new_order = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'purchase.order','create', [{'partner_id':VENDOR_ID_soucastky,'product_uom':1, 'bom_id':product.odoo_id, 'product_qty': 1.0}],)

order_line = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'purchase.order.line', 'create', [{ 'name': 'NAME TEXT','product_qty': 1, date_planned': ....... 'order_id': new_order}])
```

You will have to determine the appropriate values for your `new_order` and `order_line` record. Repeat the `order_line` as necessary.