# How to update order total amount after attaching order id to the order item execute api ? (odoo12.0)

Tags: node.js, api, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-12

I want to create an order using odoo-xml-rpc using node js. Write now i created order first and then I am creating the order item as mentioned in the following url :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40595869/363661

```
odoo.execute_kw('pos.order', 'create', params, function (err, value) { //first creating order
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(value)
        var inParams = [];
        inParams.push({
            'order_id' : value //passing previous executed order_id to order item
    })
        var params = [];
        params.push(inParams);
        odoo.execute_kw('pos.order.line', 'create', params, function (err, value) { // then create order item with that order id
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            res.send('order item created')
        });

});
```

The logic here is first we create an order and pass that order id to the line item creating api. But the problem here is "amount_total" is mandatory when creating order and after attaching order id to order item the order amount is not updating . How can we manage order subtotal using api? ( I am using nodejs xml-rpc)

Comment: Never worked with the POS, but have you tried calling the compute method which is computing the total amount of `pos.order`?

Comment: But for creating an order we have to provide order total amount, because its a mandatory field. If we compute it will give me the value which i provided during the time of creation.

Comment: Okay, i'm looking into Odoo 11.0 and `pos.order.amount_total` is a computed field. Why should you provide it on creation???

Comment: because it is giving me that field is mandatory when i didnt pass that value